# Apache Camel Kafka Connector: write to GCS in Avro format

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to consume events from Kafka which are in Protobuf and write them to GCS with Apache Camel Kafka Connector. I use Protobuf converter so events have both value and schema attached.
Would it be possible for me to write those events to Google Cloud Storage in Avro format (GenericDatumWriter with schema)?
I would also like to batch events into bigger files.

I could not find examples of writing files in Avro, any guidance would be appreciated!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. To use the official Confluent [ProtobufConverter](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/protobuf-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/protobuf/ProtobufConverter.java), a Confluent schema registry is needed. This official ProtobufConverter is able to convert bytes that are serialised by probobuf.
2. Consider using [Kafka Connect GCS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-gcs-sink/current/overview.html).

   - The first question is: why [Apache Camel connector](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/0.11.0/index.html) is chosen?
   - `toConnectData` method in converters returns [SchemaAndValue](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaAndValue.html) which can be converted to Avro/Parquet/JSON schema and data. This is the very reason why GCS connector is able to support multiple output formats.

Comment: I use custom ProtobufConverter which doesn't need Schema registry and provides SchemaAndValue.
To answer your question Apache Camel is chosen is because I don't use Confluent platform and don't have Confluent license, and GCS Sink from Confluent needs a license. Apache Camel is free, so I was hoping I could use it to do the same thing, but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: I see. Please refer to the Kafka Connect s3 connector's source code: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/tree/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3. Concepts inside, such as formats and writers, should be very help to your implementation.